# C# Write Word at the end, if string pattern contains

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-core

I am trying to write code,

any line which contains word 'ocean', I will write 'water' at the end

how would I conduct this with RegeEx?

**Sample:**

```
test1

abcdocean123 


test2
test3
```

**Result (keeps all other spacing in file):**

```
test1

abcdocean123 water


test2
test3
```

**Code Attempt:**

```
    public string FileRead(string path)
    {
        content = File.ReadAllText(path);
        return content;
    }

    public string FileChange()
    {

        var lines = content.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, @"\bocean\b\n", "water \n"));
        content = String.Join("\n", lines);
        return content;
    }
```

Comment: You do not seem to have `ocean` as a whole word. Why regex then? Just check if a line contains `ocean` and append `water` to the end of those that have it.

Comment: I added both non-regex and a regex solutions. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54622282/3832970).

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if a line contains `ocean`, and, if yes, append the `water` to that line only:

```
var content = "test1\n\nabcdocean123 \n\n\ntest2\ntest3";
var lines = content.Split(new[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
            .Select(line => line.Contains("ocean") ? $"{line}water" : line);
return string.Join("\n", lines);
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/EaicxS)

If you still need to use a regex replace `line.Contains("ocean")` with `Regex.IsMatch(line, @"\bocean\b")`, or whatever regex you need there. Just note that `\b` is a word boundary and `\bocean\b` will match only when not enclosed with word chars (digits,  letters or underscores).

Note you should rely on splitting with a newline without removing any empty lines, and when joining the lines back you won't lose any empty ones.

If you really want to continue your journey with regex, you may use

```
var content = "test1\n\nabcdocean123 \n\n\ntest2\ntest3";
content = Regex.Replace(content, @"ocean.*", "$&water");
// If your line endings are CRLF, use
// content = Regex.Replace(content, @"ocean[^\r\n]*", "$&water");
Console.WriteLine(content);
```

See [this C# demo](https://ideone.com/8hSnfh)

Here, `ocean.*` matches `ocean` substring and `.*` matches the rest of the *line* and `$&` replaces with the match found and then `water` is added. `[^\r\n]` is preferable if your line endings may include CR and as `.` matches CR, it is safer to use `[^\r\n]`, any char but CR and LF.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
Regex.Replace(line, @"(ocean)(\w+)", "$1water $2\n");
```

[Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Tql4HS)

Comment: I don't think you regex matches `abcdocean123`, does it?

Comment: thanks, doesn't seem to be working yet, I will keep researching

Comment: Can you please check again?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `Regex` at all in your case, if I got your question right.

You can just check wheter a string contains the `ocean` phrase and append the `water` word then.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    private static readonly string Token = "ocean";
    private static readonly string AppendToken = "water";
    public static void Main()
    {
        var mylist = new List<string>(new string[] { "firststring", "asdsadsaoceansadsadas", "onemoreocean", "notOcccean" });
        var newList = mylist.Select(str => {
            if(str.Contains(Program.Token)) {
                return str + " " +Program.AppendToken;
            }
            return str;
        });
        foreach (object o in newList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(o);
        }
    }
}
```

You can run this code on [DotnetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LTIhJB)